# Better option then ImageMagick or Canvas for resizing images in Android

Tags: android, imagemagick

I trying to achieve good quality image resize in Android. I'm trying all methods listed here on SO and that I could find on Google, but I still can't find a good solution.

To exemplify what I'm trying to achieve and what problems I'm having, I'm posting 3 images with the different results. Basically I'm just getting a big image from SD card, resizing and cropping it.

Here is the desired result, achieved on Photoshop:
[image: resize with photoshop]

And this is when I use the tradicional method of drawing on canvas
[image: draw on canvas]

And this result is when I use ImageMagick. It's better, but in some devices it takes minutes to resize (not cool for a mobile app)
[image: resize with imagemagick]

So, here is my code using the canvas method:

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0].path_source, o);

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = false;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
options.inSampleSize = Utils.calculateInSampleSize(o, 640, 640);

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(params[0].path_source, options);

... calculate right x, y for cropping ..

Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postScale(new_width/(float)width, new_width/(float)width);
m.postRotate(rotation);

Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 640, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.setMatrix(m);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);

canvas.drawBitmap(image, -x, -y, paint);

FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput(Utils.NOME_ARQUIVO_FOTO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
result.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
```

Now here is the code using ImageMagick:

```
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(params[0].path_source);
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(info);

//I can optionally use sampleImage for better performance, but worse quality (still better then android canvas)
//image = image.sampleImage(new_sampled_width, new_sampled_height);

image = image.scaleImage(new_width, new_height);
image = image.cropImage(new Rectangle(x, y, 640, 640));
image = image.rotateImage(rotation);

byte blob[] = image.imageToBlob(info);
FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput(Utils.NOME_ARQUIVO_FOTO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(blob);
fos.close();
```

Edit:
I'm using Android 2.3.4 on a Xperia Play for testing

Edit 2:
Saving with CompressFormat.PNG achieves near perfect result! Thanks FunkTheMonk for the tip! Only problem is that I use ImageMagick for blending this image with another later in the code, and I couldn't manage to build ImageMagick with PNG support

Comment: You might wish to explain *precisely* what you do not like about your two candidate output images.

Comment: They look ok to me... is the performance you're worried about?

Comment: Look at the color banding in the white parts of the photo. Thanks!

Comment: About performance: using canvas is nearly instantaneous, but with ImageMagick it took 28 seconds to generate that image. It's just too slow

Comment: Sure the colour banding isn't a jpg artefact?

Comment: I'm compressing with result.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); Shouldn't it use the best quality possible? I'll try out with PNG

Comment: Damn it, you are right. In PNG worked much better.. Only problem is my blending method used later in my code doesn't support PNG... Well, baby steps. Thanks!

Comment: FunkTheMonk, can you post as an answer, so I can accept it?